# Can you have embedded when.applys() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jqxhr, .when

I'm trying to use 2 $.when.apply()'s with $.ajax and $.getJSON.  I'm trying to embed one inside the other, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here's the outline:

```
var jxhr = [];
var kxhr = [];

$.when($.getJSON('stuff.js', function(cart){
    //Grab Stuff
})).then(function(){
       for(i<stuff)
       {
           jxhr.push($.getJSON(array[stuff])
       }

       $.when.apply($, jxhr).done(function()
       {
           for(i<array2)
           {
               kxhr.push($.getJSON(array2[morestuff]))

           }
           $.when.apply($, kxhr).done(function())
           {
               //Finish up here.
               //Not running.
           }
       });
}
```

There are some syntax errors from me pulling bits of code out, but the structure should be there.  The problem is that the second $.when.apply() doesn't run.  Is this a restriction?  Is there a better way to structure this code that doesn't use the embedded whens?

Comment: Shouldn't you really place the second `$.when` outside the first one, otherwise what's the point of using `$.when` if you call it everytime you add a promise to the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more vertical chaining of promises approach. Since `$.getJSON` itself returns promise, no need to wrap first call in `$.when`. Note that the 2 `then's` have to resolve in sequence before the final `done` is called

```
$.getJSON(url, function(cart) {
   $('body').append('<p>First getJSON call made</p>');
}).then(function(){
  var jxhr = [];
   $('body').append('<p>Start first loop then</p>')
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    jxhr.push(getSomeData('Loop 1'))
  }      
  return  $.when.apply($, jxhr)
}).then(function(){
   var kxhr = [];
  $('body').append('<p>Start second loop then</p>')
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      kxhr.push(getSomeData('Loop2'))
    }
   return $.when.apply(null, kxhr)
}).done(function(){
   $('body').append('<p>DONE!</p>');

});


function getSomeData(loop) {
  return  $.getJSON(url, function(res) {
      $('body').append('<p>'+loop+' getJSON call made</p>');
  })
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/n28DylCJl7uhRIFfHJ6T?p=preview)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[UPDATED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0GjXUI8FEcML1HB6KaH3?p=preview)**</kbd> (slightly more real world data processing with nested array data output)

Comment: Thank you, this ends up being so much cleaner and works great.

Comment: np...got my head unraveled a bit about chains with big loops in them by doing it